# Django oscar paypal

Tags: django, paypal, django-oscar

I am using `'django-oscar'` for ecommerce website.
I integrated `'django-oscar-paypal'` for payment system. However, I have a small issue in transmitting correct data to `'paypal-redirect'`.

The address on checkout page appears correctly and it includes `'address, contact, and instruction'`.

However, when I click on paypal button to redirect, the address appears correctly but the name slightly changes (it just omits the title) with missing contact and instruction. If I try a different address on the website, the name includes the title but still `contact/instruction` are missing.

After paying and coming back to preview page, the whole address section seems to be stuck with whatever was already inserted in the paypal website and I do not see the contact and instruction. I have set the paypal settings so that the address cannot be amended in the paypal-redirect page.

Is there a fix to this?

I have attached the screenshots.

Thank you in advance!

(Checkout) https://i.stack.imgur.com/35x1r.png

(Paypal) https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVNtq.png

(Preview - after paypal-redirect)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGqgX.png

Comment: I may have sorted out myself! 
I have commented out the whole of 
`def get_shipping_address(self, basket):`
and it is displaying exactly how I wanted it to (checkout details = preview details). I hope this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: PayPal supports 2 options - either you send PYPL an address and tell that I don't want the user to choose another address or you allow user to select and then use that to show on your shipping address. you seem to be doing the former ?

Comment: Yes. But before commenting those line out, the instruction and phone number disappeared from paypal/preview and it wouldn't display under dashboard as well. Now it all seems to be working well! Thank you.